# How could we print selected annotation to console?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am new in swift, here is a solution to add an annotation by long gesture touch, How could we print selected annotation to console ?

**Swift 4**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController , MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView : MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let longPressRecogniser = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MapViewController.handleTap(_:)))
    longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0225,longitude: 72.5714)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "iOSDevCenter-Kirit Modi"
    annotation.subtitle = "Ahmedabad"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

and here is function for adding annotation :

```
    @objc func handleTap(_ gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{

    let location = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
    let coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    // Add annotation:
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: For annotation tap you have a delegate MKMapViewDelegate. Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452393-mapview

Comment: Here is solution for Objective-C check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461709/detecting-selected-annotation-to-change-pin-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapView:didSelect` method.

e.g.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("selected annotation", view.annotation)
    print("selected annotation", view.annotation?.title)
    print("selected annotation", view.annotation?.coordinate)
}
```

Don't forget to set `mapView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`.